# Formal words for "study hard" and "study roughly"?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing my university application application, and want to explain why my grades during my exchange semester are not as elegant as normal semesters. I wish to express that I did not study them too carefully, and I paid my attention to something else equally meaningful.

So what **formal and positive** verbs should I use in

> Prioritizing my research over the courses, I did not ______ them, but
>   rather _____ them.

The first blank should mean "concentrate on,” and the second should mean "neglected" them.

Comment: Questions asking for writing advice are ["out of scope for this site"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @CanisLupus Why doesn't this question fall into `Word choice and usage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer to your question may be: do not fill in the blanks.

William Strunk instructs us to "make every word tell." The first part of your sentence is likely enough.

> I prioritized my research over my courses.

What else do you need to say? Furthermore, if you want a "positive" sentence, do not include a negative word such as "but" or try to excuse your actions.

To more explicitly answer your question, I think the word "prioritize" is a fantastic word in this situation, and all of the other words I can currently think of are clearly inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside whether or not this question is "in scope" - though I would say it is, since it focuses more on word usage than advice - the best I can come up with is "ruminate" and "was lax on," respectively. Other than this, though, "concentrate on" and "neglect" work just fine.